# RegEx - Changing a value

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have this text:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" id="wordpress_grazit_script">        
            var dbnurls = [];
            var dbnanchors = [];
            dbnurls.push('url');
            dbnanchors.push('anchor');
            var script = document.createElement("script");
            script.setAttribute("src", dbn_protocol+"path to js");
            script.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
            script.setAttribute("id", "grazit_script");
            document.getElementById("my-id").parentNode.appendChild(script);
    </script>
```

and I need to replace dbn_protocol+"path to js" with something else.

I have tried to use this match pattern but it matches all the way to the last );

```
    "script\\.setAttribute\\([\"']src[\"'],(.*[^\\);])(\\);)(.*)"
```

I need to spcify that I need this regex in c# .net

Thank you

Comment: What language are you using to process the script text? Is it also javascript, or something else?

Comment: Look into non-greedy matching (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3206d374.aspx). Currently your `.*` will grab all it can, you want it to grab the minimum amount possible so you will want `.*?`.

Comment: Also why not just match the pattern `"dbn_protocol+"path to js"` and replace that rather than doing more complicated things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you [Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/338068/chris) for your answer. The problem was what you said. The regex was taking greedy and going all the way to the last match. I put the '?' and it all worked.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You could match only as from the `dbn_protocol` (and use `@` symbol when defining the regex so you don't have to do a bunch of double escapes):

```
var regex = new Regex(@"dbn_protocol\+""[^""]+""");
```

[ideone example](http://ideone.com/zQKK3E).

Using the quotes will prevent the regex from matching more than `path to js`.

Comment: Thanks for the '@' advice but I do not know for sure that dbn_protocol is there always, could be any value, string or variable.

Comment: @DanielTranca Oh, I thought that the string you had, had 'dbn_protocol' statis (as in non-variable).

Answer (score 0):

If in javascript you can do it like this:

```
var result = yourScriptString.replace(
    /(script\.setAttribute\("src",)(.*)(\))/, 
    " $1'" + someUrl + "'$3");
```

See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hv7Pa/) for details.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to replace **dbn_protocol+"path to js"**,there are several ways to achieve this,first you can directly replace **dbn_protocol+"path to js"** with something new using

```
string.Replace(string searchterm,string replacementterm);
```

but as you mentioned you want the stuff in regex,so try the method below,it returns a new string(which is a new script section with **dbn_protocol+"path to js"** replaced).This should satisfy you as it's done using regex;

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"dbn_protocol\+""[^""]+""");
string newscript=r.Replace("your script's text","the replacement string");
//newscript is the script text that you need.
```

One more thing i would like to point if you need to change this absolutely once,then why you chose doing it in code while you could easily do it by hand.

Hope it works.